# How to report when failover feature is active in JAXWS SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, failover

I have a client that is built like this:

```
val strategy = new SequentialStrategy()
strategy.setAlternateAddresses(listOfAddresses)

val feature = new CircuitBreakerFailoverFeature(2, 60000)
feature.setStrategy(strategy)

val factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean()
factory.setServiceClass(classOf[MyService])
factory.setAddress(primaryAddress)
factory.setFeatures(Lists.newArrayList(feature))
factory.create().asInstanceOf[MyService]
```

The problem I have now is that I need to report to monitoring tool when my client is actually went to one of `alternative` addresses as result of problem with connection to the `primaryAddress`. But I can't find the way how to detect those switches between addresses (I thought about adding custom interceptors, but I bet there is a better way to do it). What is the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like more or less a correct way to do this is to `inject` reporting logic into TargetSelector, like this:

```
class MonitoredCircuitBreakerTargetSelector(errorReporter: Monitoring) extends CircuitBreakerTargetSelector {
  @Override
  protected void onFailure(context: FailoverTargetSelector#InvocationContext, ex: Exception)= {
    errorReporter.report(s"...")
    super.onFailure(context, ex)
  }
}
```

and then call `feature.setTargetSelector(new MonitoredCircuitBreakerTargetSelector(errorReporter))` on FailoverFeature